# Initializing a class member with another class member C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a class with two different class objects as members.  I want to initialize one of the members with another, but so far I can't seem to get this to work.

For example, `Game game(&input);` contains an error that there must be a type specified.  How might I go about doing this?

```
class KApp { 
private:
    Input input;
    Game game(&input);

};


class Input {
    Input() {};
};

class Game {
private:
    Input* input;
public:
    Game(Input & inp) : input(&inp) {}
    Game(Input* inp) : input(inp) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
class KApp { 
private:
    Input input;
    Game game;
    KApp() : game(&input) {}
};
```

What is going on with `Game game(&input);` is that you're declaring a member `game` which the compiler has picked up as a function declaration and is complaining that the parameter doesn't have a type.

This way, you're explicitly calling `Game::Game(Input*)` in the constructor of KApp (at which point input should be initialized using its default constructor).

edit - Input* vs Input&

Comment: Prefect.  Thanks man.  I see what you're saying.  I am trying to do it to soon.  I should do it when the class object constructor is called not when the class object is declared.  I made the adjustment and it worked.